# Cant load folder to import (Pycharm)

Tags: import, directory, pycharm

Hi guys I have a problem. I cant import my module "browser.py" because i cant load my third directory (here: "enums1").
Everytime I enter the dot after the directory "whatsapp", only par, not and main are shown as the only options.
[Load Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrOO3.png)

Comment: Try `Ctrl+click` (GoTo Declaration) on `whatsapp` in `from Udemy.whatsapp` - where did PyCharm bring you?